# A function which is infinitely-differentiable everywhere but continuous nowhere?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Is there a function which is infinitely-differentiable everywhere but continuous nowhere?

EDIT:  The graphic which has since been deleted was taken from my own notes, and I can clarify what definition of "differentiable" was being used there (presumably, the meaning the OP had in mind was the same).

A function is *differentiable* at $x$ iff (i) all directional derivatives at $x$ exist, and (ii) the map that sends a tangent vector to the corresponding directional derivative is continuous and linear.  (Of course, in finite dimensions, the condition "continuous" is superfluous.)  This is strictly stronger than gâteaux differentiable and strictly weaker than fréchet differentiable.  (FWIW, that this definition is nonstandard is made clear immediately following the definition, where it is contrasted with both gâteaux differentiability and fréchet differentiability.)

If you're curious, the motivation for this terminology is as follows.

1. Using all three terms allows me to be more precise, and as "fréchet differentiable" and "gâteaux differentiable" already have names, by necessity the above condition is referred to as simply "differentiable" (which I found more palatable than just making up a new term).
2. This definition is easier (and, IMHO, more natural) than fréchet differentiable, and furthermore, almost everything that is true for fréchet differentiable functions is true of functions which are differentiable in this sense (the fact in question here being the biggest exception I am aware of).
3. While this is (slightly) more difficult than the definition of gâteaux differentiable, I found that not having the derivative be a one-form 'broke' things to an unacceptable degree (for example, as I only defined the derivative of tensor fields, if the derivative itself were not a tensor field, then strictly speaking the second derivative would have been left undefined).

Comment: What do *you* mean when you say "infinitely-differentiable"?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean 'differentiable at infinitely many points'?  In any case, the function you list is differentiable _nowhere_, as can be shown with an easy argument. (None of the relevant limits exist, by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its complement)

Comment: @Michael That's an imprecise way of saying that all the derivatives $f', f'', f''', ...$ exist. But if *any* derivative exists, the first derivative exists.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : "Infinitely differentiable" means all of the derivatives exist, i.e. the first derivative, the second derivative, the third derivative, and so on. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael The fact that the function is on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is **absolutely crucial** because the answer is false in $\mathbb{R}$ (and I assumed that was what your question was about given your attempt). This is why it's important that you include all the relevant information in your post when you make it, rather than 10 comments later.

Comment: It didn't matter whether the function is on $\mathbb{R}^2$ or not. The function in the picture is not differentiable at the origin. So there is no contradiction that it is not continuous at the origin. Infinitely differentiable  everywhere except at one single point is not strong enough to force the function to be continuous at the specific point.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know what "infinitely differentiable" means; I was asking the OP because - based on their question - I wasn't sure they were using the term correctly.

Comment: It looks like the OP is talking about infinitely differentiable in a given direction (i.e. I am talking about a directional derivative)  -- this seems like it is just confusion between the existence of directional derivatives, Gateaux differentiability, and Frechet differentiability.

Comment: Your usage of 'infinitely differentiable' is far from standard. It is not clear that you are referring to any of the usual menagerie, Fréchet, Gateaux, one sided, etc.

Comment: @Michael Please don't vandalize questions even if they are your own. I rolled back to the last legible version.

Comment: The book has lousy typesetting.  Look at where the period is after the piecewise definition. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Also, "tie-up" a "loose-end" :-)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I actually never knew about this convention before.  I had always just placed my punctuation at the end of everything without really ever giving it any extra thought.  Now that you point it out though, I see it does seem to be the standard to place the punctuation at the end of the last "case".  I will be sure to fix this in the next version of the notes.

Comment: @Bungo What do you mean?  Actually, I didn't want the dash in "tie-up"---that was a mistake/typo.  That's not what you were referring to, was it?

Comment: @JonathanGleason It should be "tie up a loose end", no dashes/hyphens in either. On another note, I disagree with your point 2, IMO Fréchet differentiability is the more natural notion. And a norm is not necessary, the Fréchet derivative can be [defined for topological vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Generalization_to_topological_vector_spaces).

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh that's a good point about the Fréchet derivative being able to be generalized.  I will edit my motivation accordingly (though it's still not quite as nice in that you have to rephrase the definition in a way that it can be generalized, whereas the definition of directional derivative appearing in gâteaux just makes sense in the more general context with no modification).

Comment: @DanielFischer Also, could you explain why you find Fréchet more natural?  I have always thought of as the derivative literally as the directional derivatives, but all packaged together as a single entity, namely as a one-form, that takes in a tangent vector and spits out the directional derivative in that direction.  With this intuition, it's hard to get more natural than "All the directional derivatives exist and define a one-form.".

Comment: @JonathanGleason I've been taught - and consequently think of - the derivative as the linear approximation to the function. "Approximation" meaning precisely the definition of the Fréchet derivative. Directional derivatives were but a footnote and came immediately with an example of bad behaviour (discontinuity) despite all directional derivatives being $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay that makes perfect sense then.  With this intuition, then I agree that Fréchet is probably the more natural of the two.  In fact, moreover I might argue that, a priori, a linear approximation is a more natural thing to care about than directional derivatives per se.  I'm not sure if this warrants a rewrite of the entire chapter, but it's certainly something I'll think about.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is infinitely differentiable everywhere but $(0,0)$. As you say, it is not even continuous there.  These are not contradictory.  It is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ either.  It is differentiable in every specific direction from $(0,0)$, but for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ you can't find a $\delta \gt 0$ such that blah-blah for all points within $\delta$ of the origin.  It is crucial whether you choose the $\delta$ before I choose the direction or the other way around.  The definition I know of differentiable requires that the $\delta$ be chosen first, and your proof of non-continuity is an even stronger proof of non-differentiabiliy.  It requires that the derivative be well defined based on all points within $\delta$ of the point you are taking the derivative at. If you have a different definition of differentiable, you should state it.